# Web/Worker Role Reboot Resets Firewall Rules

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Does any one know why on rebooting web/worker instance from the Azure portal the fire wall rules set in that machine instance gets removed.

I know that the best practice is to use VNET and NSG and there is no logic from adding the rules to one instance while these rules are not being applied to the other instances but it would be nice if I know what is happening on Rebooting Instance (Not the Service) from the portal.